# Wget download speed fluctuating

Tags: linux, download, iso-image, wget

So I'm downloading an ISO from the Uberstudent website using the wget command displayed on their website. But the download speed is constantly fluctuating and I am wondering what could be causing this? I mean it goes from 2.5mb/s to 150 kb/s in a matter of seconds. How could I make it so the download speed is more consistant?

Comment: There isn't a great deal you can do as the end user.

Comment: So this is due to their upload speed? @Ramhound

Comment: @Clan - Yes; Also your own download speed.  Which is the reason you have no control over it, you receive the bandwidth you receive, outside of not saturating your "pipe" that isn't much you can do.

Comment: @Ramhound But surely a steady 30mb/s download speed should be more than enough  to provide a steady download at 2mb/s?

Comment: There are many factors that go the speed of a download.  The quality and stability of your connection is only two factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the download speed is constantly fluctuating and I am wondering
>   what could be causing this?

As mentioned in the comments, the maximum instantaneous download speed depends on the upload bandwidth of the server allocated to you and the download load bandwidth allocated to your `wget` command. Both of which can vary over time.

> How could I make it so the download speed is more consistent?

You can use the `--limit-rate` option to `wget`. So for example if you want a **consistent 1 byte per sec** download, just add the `--limit-rate=1` option to `wget`. I hope this answers your questions.